# Standardize SQL multiple AND/Where

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to make the following SQL more efficient but have not yet been successfully beyond what I have as the following. This runs in about 2 min returning avg of 800 rows. I can't use temp table. Any suggestions?

```
Select POP.Account_Number, IP.IP_Id_Src, 
 POP.Ip_Name_Full, INFO_Default_Hmp.Date_Solicitation, 
 INFO.BAL_PRIN_AMT, UDD.USER_DEFINED_5V_14, 
 POP.Process_Stop_Code, POP.Mail_Code

 FROM POP, IP, INFO, INFO_Default_Hmp, 
 INFO_Participation_Item, UDD

 WHERE (INFO.Account_Number=POP.Account_Number 
 AND INFO.Appl_Id=POP.Appl_Id 
 AND INFO.Bank_Number=POP.Bank_Number 
 AND INFO_Default_Hmp.Bank_Number=POP.Bank_Number 
 AND INFO_Default_Hmp.Account_Number=POP.Account_Number 
 AND INFO_Default_Hmp.Appl_Id=POP.Appl_Id 
 AND POP.Bank_Number=INFO_Participation_Item.Bank_Number 
 AND POP.Appl_Id=INFO_Participation_Item.Appl_Id 
 AND POP.Account_Number=INFO_Participation_Item.Account_Number 
 AND INFO_Participation_Item.Involved_Party_Id_Investor=IP.Involved_Party_Id_Investor 
 AND UDD.Account_Number=POP.Account_Number 
 AND UDD.Bank_Number=POP.Bank_Number 
 AND POP.Appl_Id=UDD.Appl_Id)  
 AND ((POP.Appl_Id='FL' 
 AND POP.Account_Status_Code='A' 
 AND INFO.Bal_Prin_Amt>0 
 AND UDD.User_Defined_5v_14='S1'))
```

Comment: Did you look at the execution plan?

Comment: Your statement is joining 7 tables and applying some filters. Use `JOIN` statements for the joins and leave only the filters in the `WHERE` statement. This won't make it run faster but it will make it readable. After that, ensure the join and filter columns are indexed - nothing affects database performance as much as indexing

Comment: What database are you using, what is the execution plan, how much data is there in the source tables? Do you have any indexes on the source tables?

Comment: SQL 2008 - these tables are used for multiple reporting purposes by various users so I am limited in regards to playing with the Indexes but I will validate they are appropriately placed.  The source tables are daily tables and load thousands of records 7 days a week.

Answer (score 0):

Maximize the use of indexes for the columns you frequently filter and join, especially the int fields.

Also, let us know which RDBMS you are using by adding that tag to your post

Comment: Thank you I will validate indexes on the various tables. Unfurtunately because these tables are used by multiple users for a large number of reporting needs my ability to modify those may be limited.